# Real singular (co)homology of projective plane/Klein bottle without Mayer-Vietoris/Van-Kampen

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm reading differential geometry books and trying to learn the singular (co)homology with real coefficients of the Klein bottle and projective plane by their fundamental rectangles. Here is the fundamental domain for the projective plane:

[image: Fundamental polygon]

Many books prove that the 1st singular cohomology of the projective plane with real coefficients is 0 using fancy theorems I don't get. My question is:

As a student of physics, I would like to know how one can visually see from the fundamental rectangle that the 1st (co)homology ($H^1$ or $H_1$) with real coefficients of the projective plane is trivial. Similar, how can one see visually from the fundamental rectangle of the Klein bottle that its 1st (co)homology with real coefficients is $\mathbb{R}$? (All I want to understand is the 1st (co)homology, not the 0th or 2nd, which I do understand.)

How to answer this question? For example, take the projective plane. Consider the closed curve BA from the upper right to the lower left. What is that curve the boundary of? Can you draw the answer on the rectangle? Similarly, for the Klein bottle (the above diagram with the $A$'s pointing to the right.) The vertical line right down the middle of the rectangle is a closed curve. What is that curve the boundary of? Can you draw the answer on the rectangle? (For the Klein bottle, the curve going horizonally in the middle generates the homology.) I do not want any high-level theorems like Mayer-Vietoris or Seifert-Van Kampen or deformation retracts or $\pi_1(\mathbb{S}^1)$ or removing points or using covers or other tricks people try to impress me with. I just want to understand these examples not by using fancy or impressive theorems, but conceptually by explicitly showing some closed curves are boundaries.

Comment: You might want to use a $\Delta$-complex structure. Check Hatcher's book.

Comment: Seems like you're literally chucking out from the list any actual theorems which you can use to calculate and not guess what the cohomology groups are, by the looks of your question. In any case, try thinking of $\Bbb{RP}^2$ as a circle with a disk attached by a degree 2 map (this is equivalent to the fundamental polygon description; why?). Then intuitively the cycle going once around the circle is your generator of $H_1$ and if it goes twice it becomes zero (push through the disk you have attached), so $H_1$ should be $\Bbb Z/2$.

Comment: This is not a full answer, but if you are interested in homology $H_1$ and can digest the claim that it is the abelianization of the fundamental group, then you immediately get that the first homology group of the projective space is $\Bbb Z_2$ (not $0$!). The fundamental group is generated by ''$a+b$'' in your picture. And $2\times (a+b)$ is contractible, as this curve goes around the whole square boundary.

Comment: I just noted you were asking for real coefficients. That might be a bit harder to visualize, but think of it as removing the torsion (more or less 'cause any module over a field is free). $\Bbb Z/2$ only has torsion, so homology becomes $0$. Also people are not reading your things carefully because you're putting paragraphs on stuff like "don't use big tools to impress me" and whatnot which are not relevant to the question. Better remove it and make the question clear, the summary of which should be "what is the intuition behind $H_1(\Bbb{RP}^2; \Bbb R) = 0$".

Comment: @Julie Such comments don't help your case. Using the universal coefficients theorems (which is trivial for a field like $\Bbb R$, meaning you can check it without any fancy arguments), you get what Balarka said.

Comment: Do not deface your questions.

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct to assume that the vanishing of the first cohomology implies every closed curve must be a boundary. The curve $BA$ you mention, for instance, is not one, as would show up in the fundamental group or in first homology with integer coefficients, though not in the first cohomology.

With real coefficients, $BA$ represents zero in cohomology because $BABA=2BA$ is a boundary. $H^1$ is supposed to be a real vector space, so if twice some cycle is zero, the cycle itself must be as well.